# No audio heard unless facing audio source unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script, to play a sound clip when a footstep is taken. I use events in the animation tab, and when I play the sound, it will only be audible if i am looking at the character, or npc, the audio source is in fact on the character, but i don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Any chance you are culling objects out of vision?

Answer (score 0):

On your AudioSource, you could play around with the 3D sound settings:
[image: 3D sound settings]